# .htaccess rewrite all queries to static page

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite, 301-redirect

I have an account where hundreds of inbound links to their calender are showing up as 404 (they moved their site to a new platform). I would like to make a wildcard redirection of all URLs with a query to their old event calender to land on a new static page, and do the same for their webstore queries. I've tried several variations, but can't seem to get it to work.

CASE 1: 
I need to redirect URLs like these (note the difference between "showDay" and "showWeek"):

apps/calendar/showWeek?calID=5107976&year=2011&month=7&day=10
apps/calendar/showDay?calID=5107976&year=2011&month=9&day=10

To:

http://domain.com/events/

CASE 2:
And also URLs like these:

apps/webstore/products/show/1927074

TO:
http://subdomain.domain.com/

I can't seem to get the syntax right to take all of the URLS and redirect them. I'm looking for the equivalent of a wildcard like "apps/calendar/*" would give you at a command line.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much! You definitely helped me!

I did have to add a question mark at the end of the domain I'm redirecting to in order to strip out the query:

```
    RedirectMatch Permanent apps/calendar/?.* http://domain/com/events/?
    RedirectMatch Permanent apps/webstore/?.* http://subdomain.domain.com/?
```

Answer (score 0):

For the calendar URLs:

`RedirectMatch Permanent apps/calendar/?.* http://domain/com/events/`

And the webstore:

`RedirectMatch Permanent apps/webstore/?.* http://subdomain.domain.com/`

You don't need rewrites.